# kubernetes failed to start pod due to ContainerCannotRun

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes. Recently set up kubernetes cluster with 1 master and 1 node.

I am able to start a docker container by running 
`sudo docker run <docker-image>` in my node machine.

But i failed to start docker container as a pod using kubernetes yml file. 
by running `sudo kubectl create -f deployment.yml`

I describe the pod information and saw this error message.

```
      Last State:   Terminated
      Reason:       ContainerCannotRun
      Message:      OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"HOSTNAME\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
      Exit Code:    128
```

docker container supposes to start a java executable. 
this is my deployment file

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service1-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: service1
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      # Port accessible inside cluster
      port: 26666
      # Port to forward to inside the pod
      targetPort: 26666
      # Port accessible outside cluster
      nodePort: 26666
  type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service1-depolyment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: service1
          image: service1-docker-image
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 26666
          # args: ["HOSTNAME", "KUBERNETES_PORT"]
```

In this deployment file, I try to create a nginx and one java web applicaition service.

It is because i defined wrong apiVersion and kind ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message matches the commented-out `args:` line, FWIW.  When you run the image locally, do you pass any options to `docker run` besides `-p` and maybe `-d`?

Comment: when i run locally, i will use something like this 
`sudo docker run -d -p 80:26666 service1-docker-image`

Comment: You cloud delete the line of "HOSTNAME" and give a try.

Comment: Could you specify what are you expecting? According to https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes "If you supply only **args** for a Container, the default Entrypoint defined in the Docker image is run with the args that you supplied."

Can you provide your Dockerfile?

Are using microk8s/minikube/cloud? On GCP I received error about nodePort: `The Service "service1-service" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 26666: provided port is not in the valid range. The range of valid ports is 30000-32767`

Comment: @PjoterS provided ports can be configured from here. `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yam` add one more config `--service-node-port-range=20000-32767`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this error `exec: \"HOSTNAME\": executable file not found in $PATH`

I had a similar error since the container could not locate the docker "CMD" binary since I gave it the wrong path. Check the path to the file and that should do the trick.

Comment: Thats was perfect. Thanks. Faced same issue with "ContainerCannotRun" error and it was location was exe that caused it.